# How can I "frontrun" alerts (trigger before level is reached)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am creating Support/Resistance line from an array and would love to have the option to add alerts to trigger before that level is actually reached (specify a %-value).

**Questions**

1. How to add alerts to array generated lines
2. How to make them respect a % value (e.g. if getting 5% close trigger the alert)
3. (Dreaming of it): Choice to allow me to only trigger that alert on weekdays/exclude weekend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to get the values from the array and work with those values
2. You should set a new variable based on your calculations. Then use that variable in your alert condition
3. You can use `dayofweek` for that

Comment: Thanks, make sense while reading. Since I already live the function hell, do you got link (for me to read/learn) on how to make an array of a multiple arrays while keeping their origin ID intact (if possible at all)?